# ¿Cómo puedo iniciar proyecto en C# MVC tomando un parámetro de otra página?

Tags: c#, mvc

Quiero que mi proyecto *(página web `C#` `MVC`)* sea llamado desde otra página (la cual mandará una clave de acceso).

¿Cómo  podría hacer para iniciar mi proyecto ahora que esta en pruebas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias utilizar [`window.open(url)`](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiK45CJjPDUAhVG9IMKHVxVC4IQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_open.asp&usg=AFQjCNFM3KouiJqQXih8N94QncXg0e_ODw&cad=rjt) que abre una nueva ventana en el navegado y le pasas la url de tu pagina con tu clase de acceso.

Por ejemplo:

```
function abrirWebApp()
{
      window.open("https://www.google.com.do/?#newwindow=1&q=stackoverflow+en+español");
 }
```

Comment: Supongo que al iniciar mi proyecto debo de pedir el parámetro que se mandará @EinerSantana

Comment: Exacto @AnahíTobías

Comment: gracias @EinerSantana